# How to change preloaded video HTML5 Phaser?

Tags: html, video, preload, phaser-framework

Hi i am using html5 Phaser game engine to make a video flipbook.

I load my videos in my preloader like this.

```
this.load.video('myVideo1', 'assets/video/video1.mp4');
this.load.video('myVideo2', 'assets/video/video2.mp4');
```

I add my video to my game like this:

```
this.video = this.add.video('myVideo1');
```

I want to use the change source like this;

```
this.video = this.add.video('myVideo' + curScene.toString);
```

I am using the last part wrong... But i wana use my preloaded video :(

Some video information here: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/video/change-source

Comment: what is in curScene.toString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this.add.video` to change the source; you should rather use something like this:

`this.video.changeSource('assets/video/video' + curScene.toString() + '.mp4');`

Note that it's not the cache key that is used - it's the full URL to the second video (assuming that `curScene.toString()` will indeed return "1" or "2").

Comment: This doesnt preload videos though does it?